# How do I resize the image so it fits on the screen(python)

Tags: python, opencv, image-resizing

I have a machine learning facial recognition script that reads an image that you put in the same directory as it, and displays it with the faces labelled. However, if I give it an image that is to large to fit on my screen, it just doesn't fit. How would I resize this image within the Python script to fit my screen. 
Thanks

CODE

```
import face_recognition as fr
import os
import cv2
import face_recognition
import numpy as np
from time import sleep


def get_encoded_faces():
    """
    looks through the faces folder and encodes all
    the faces

    :return: dict of (name, image encoded)
    """
    encoded = {}

    for dirpath, dnames, fnames in os.walk("./faces"):
        for f in fnames:
            if f.endswith(".jpg") or f.endswith(".png"):
                face = fr.load_image_file("faces/" + f)
                encoding = fr.face_encodings(face)[0]
                encoded[f.split(".")[0]] = encoding

    return encoded


def unknown_image_encoded(img):
    """
    encode a face given the file name
    """
    face = fr.load_image_file("faces/" + img)
    encoding = fr.face_encodings(face)[0]

    return encoding


def classify_face(im):
    faces = get_encoded_faces()
    faces_encoded = list(faces.values())
    known_face_names = list(faces.keys())

    face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(img)
    unknown_face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(img, face_locations)

    face_names = []
    for face_encoding in unknown_face_encodings:
        # See if the face is a match for the known face(s)
        matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(faces_encoded, face_encoding)
        name = "Unknown"

        # use the known face with the smallest distance to the new face
        face_distances = face_recognition.face_distance(faces_encoded, face_encoding)
        best_match_index = np.argmin(face_distances)
        if matches[best_match_index]:
            name = known_face_names[best_match_index]

        face_names.append(name)

        for (top, right, bottom, left), name in zip(face_locations, face_names):
            # Draw a box around the face
            cv2.rectangle(img, (left-20, top-20), (right+20, bottom+20), (255, 0, 0), 2)

            # Draw a label with a name below the face
            cv2.rectangle(img, (left-20, bottom -15), (right+20, bottom+20), (255, 0, 0), cv2.FILLED)
            font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX
            cv2.putText(img, name, (left -20, bottom + 15), font, 1.0, (255, 255, 255), 2)


    # Display the resulting image
    while True:

        cv2.imshow('Image', img)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            return face_names 


print(classify_face("test.jpg"))
```

As you can see, I have added some comments to help with the process. 
Any help would be gratefully appreciated!

Comment: Can't you just use `cv2.imwrite`. I always do that when image doesn't fit.

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` or `facial-recognition` question - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow`, you wouldn't have this problem then. OpenCV does that most of the times that is why I prefer `matplotlib`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Worked well, however, it now displays two images, the new one using matplotlib, and the old, over sized one. Also, the colours are distorted, whites are now blue?

Answer (score 0):

You can install the following module:

```
pip install screeninfo
```

Then use the following code to get the screen dimensions:

```
import screeninfo

for monitor in screeninfo.get_monitors():
     print(str(monitor))
```

Extract the dimensions from the string and use the cv.resize() function to fit the image to your screen.

If you already know your screen resolution, an alternative solution would be to add a simple if statement, if the dimensions of your images exceed your monitor's dimensions, you can resize them to your current dimensions.